# Добавление элемента предпоследним

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица с данными и строка содержащая пустые ячейки (input) для ввода данных от пользователя. После ввода данных в ячейки, готовая строка сохраняется в таблицу. Мне нужно добавлять новую строку не в конец таблицы (`table.append(userString);`), а на предпоследнюю позицию (не могу же я написать *append-1*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого Вам нужно найти последнюю строку и у нее вызвать метод `before`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var idx = 0;
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.last').before('<tr><td>' + idx + '</td></tr>');
    idx++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="last"><td>Last Row</td></tr>
</table>
<button>Add</button>
```

Comment: Подскажите, а если мне нужно добавить новую строку к существующей таблице (table)?
$('.last').before(newTr);  
Как мне указать что добавляться строка должна в конкретную таблицу? 
/* это не верно, но логику мою Вы поймете:
 ('table.last').before(newTr);*/

Comment: @Yiulia У Вас на странице много таблиц и в каждую нужно добавлять строки?